# resizing tableview when keyboard is shown and hidden

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, keyboard, uitextfield

I have a view controller with a UITableView and UITextField. I subscribe to notifications about when the keyboard opens and closes and use the information about the keyboard height to adjust the size and position of the UITableView and UITextField.

But I have two problems.

When the keyboard opens the UITextField seems to automatically reposition itself - which would have been fine if it was positioned correctly. It seems to have a vertical offset of the same as the height of the Tab Bar Controller.

How do I disable that the UITextField tries to reposistion itsel when the keyboard opens?

The second problem is that when the keyboard is open the table part of UITableView seems to be too long - I can scroll far below the last element in the table (I guess similar to the height of the keyboard). When the keyboard is opened I set the new height of the UITableView like this (kbSize is the size of the keyboard):

```
CGSize size = self.view.frame.size;
self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0f, 0,0f, size.width, size.height - kbSize.height);
```

What am I missing here? Do I somehow need to set the 'height' of the table and not only the frame?

Thanks, Ole

Answer (score 3):

If you change your parent class from `UIViewController` to `UITableViewController` the resizing of the view while the keyboard shows up will be then done by the OS.

Answer (score 1):

you just take 1 viewcontroller class and inside put tableview when keyboard will popup jest set the viewcontroller frame with y = y-140......
like this

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionNone forView:self.view cache:YES];

    scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, -140, 320, 460);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    return YES;
}
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionNone forView:self.view cache:YES];
    scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```